# Populate column between two random numbers with an average of x?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to populate a column with integers between x and x, but I would like to specify the average for that number being generated. For instance I would like to populate column A1 with integers between 0 and 15 with 5 being the average of that number generated.

I know about the RANDBETWEEN(x,x) function, but I don't know how to specify the average.

Thanks,

Nick T

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an accurate average: 2 information is important a) you have to store every number that was genrated and b) how many times needs to generate. 
I dont think we have existing formula meet your requirements, therefore i would suggest you could write a custom function to generate the random number

```
RandAverage(startNum, endNum, averNum, count)
```